Using `:=` with mutate
I have the following code chunks. I want to make sure that it is valid to use of := with mutate as in the following two chunks of code.
I have consulted here but was not sure if it is valid to use := with mutate: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html
This is one chunk of code:
for(i in seq_along(suffix_22_cols)) {
  new_col_name <- str_replace(suffix_22_cols[i], "_22$", "") # Create new column name without suffix
  col_22 <- suffix_22_cols[i]
  col_nsc2 <- suffix_nsc2_cols[i]
  
  # Check if both columns exist before attempting to coalesce.
  
  if(col_22 %in% names(combined_dataframe) && col_nsc2 %in% names(combined_dataframe)) {
    combined_dataframe <- combined_dataframe %>%
      mutate(!!sym(new_col_name) := coalesce(!!sym(col_22), !!sym(col_nsc2)))
  }
}


# This is my second chunk of code:

# Corresponding _n_experts columns
n_experts_columns <- paste0(columns, "_n_experts")

# Loop over each column pair
for (i in seq_along(columns)) {
  column <- columns[i]
  n_experts_column <- n_experts_columns[i]
  
  expert_dataset <- expert_dataset %>%
    mutate(!!sym(column) := case_when(
      .data[[n_experts_column]] < n ~ NA_real_,
      .default = .data[[column]]
    ))
}

expert_dataset <- expert_dataset %>%
  group_by(country, poppa_id) %>%
  ungroup()



I know my question might sound a bit weird, but do you test your code? From my experience, the syntax looks correct, and using := to dynamically assign names to new columns usually works fine for me.

Hallo, thanks for the answer. Yes, I check the code and it works great. For some reason I just had my doubts about the use of := with dplyr.
